# NODE.JS, Express, mySQL2 : Issues appending an object inside of another object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, mysql2

I'm having an issue in trying to add the results of a query into an object. I am new to Node and Express so I apologize if I am making some stupid mistakes. I have been reading docs and watching videos pretty much non stop while I try to get this to work. Async is still wierd for my brain so I am sure I am doing things wrong, the function I placed seems wrong, I would appreciate so much any videos or articles you know of that could aid my comprehension as well haha!

Basically I have a table called stages, where the user can add or remove stages. I am pulling all the stages and then trying to add the projects that belong in those stages as an array of objects.

Ok so here is the code:

```
var myStages = []; //Global variable to hold stages.

//Get all the Stages
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(`Connected as ID ${connection.threadId}`);

        //Query
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM solarcrm_stages', (err, rows) => {
            connection.release();

            if(!err) {
                getProjects(rows);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
        function getProjects(stages) {
            myStages = stages;

            Object.entries(myStages).forEach(entry => {
                const[key] = entry;

                connection.query('SELECT * FROM project WHERE iProjectStage = ?', [myStages[key]['iStageID']], (err, rows) => {
                    connection.release();

                    if(!err) {
                        myStages[key]['Projects'] = rows;
                        console.log(myStages);     //Projects shows up as 'Projects: [ [TextRow] ]'            
                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    })
})
```

The current result I get is this, Stage 1 has projects that should appear but shows [TextRow], Stage 2 should be empty as it is:

```
[

TextRow {

iStageID: 1,

sStageName: 'Stage1',

sStateIcon: 'null',

bActive: 1,

iOrderID: 1,

sStageDesc: null,

Projects: [ [TextRow] ]

},

TextRow {

iStageID: 2,

sStageName: 'Stage 2',

sStateIcon: 'null',

bActive: 1,

iOrderID: 2,

sStageDesc: null,

Projects: []

}

]
```

Thank you so much for any help or guidance you can offer.

Comment: welcome to stackOveFlow

Comment: Have you found any solution yet I'm having the same issue.